# Functions giving self-adjoint elements of the algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

I was going over some results from a class I finished, and I am stuck on the following in $\color{red}{\textrm{red}}$.

> **Theorem**: Suppose that $A$ is a $C^\ast$-algebra and that $b\in A$. Then $b^\ast b$ is positive$^{[1]}$.

*Proof*. Start by defining
\begin{align*}
    f(t)=
    \begin{cases}
        \sqrt{t} & \text{if } t\geq0\\
        0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
    \quad\text{and}\quad
    g(t)=
    \begin{cases}
        0 & \text{if } t\geq0\\
        \sqrt{-t} & \text{otherwise}.
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
Then for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $f(t)g(t)=g(t)f(t)=0$ and $f(t)^2-g(t^2)=t$. $\color{red}{\textrm{Since $f$ and $g$ both vanish at $0$, we get self-adjoint elements of $A$ via}}$
\begin{align*}
    \color{red}{\textrm{$u=f(b^\ast b)\quad\text{and}\quad v=g(b^\ast b)$}}.
\end{align*}
Then $uv=vu=0$ and $u^2-v^2=b^\ast b$. But then $vb^\ast bv=v(u^2-v^2)v=-v^4$. Thus $\sigma((bv)^\ast bv)=\sigma(-v^4)\subset(-\infty,0]$. Thus $-v^4=0$. Since $v$ is self-adjoint, this means $v=0$. But then $b^\ast b=u^2$, and $u^2$ is positive.

---

$^{[1]}$ Here an element $a$ is called *positive* if $a$ is self-adjoint and $\sigma(a)\subset[0,\infty)$.

---

I know that the element $b^\ast b$ is self-adjoint. Also, the maps are really the functional calculus, so that $f(b^\ast b)$ is not really $\sqrt{b^\ast b}$.

Comment: As $f$ is real valued and continuous , the element $f(b^*b)$ is self-adjoint. I do not understand the emphasis on $f(0)=0$ besides the continuity at $t=0.$ Actually $f(b^*b)=(b^*b)^{1/2},$ i.e. the unique positive element whose square is equal $b^*b.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: Regarding your second statement: That is true if I know that $b^\ast b$ is positive, which is the theorem I am trying to prove.

Comment: I've taken it into account, as the red part was clarified, and the rest of the proof should be fine. Although I do not get why the sentence with first Thus implies the one with the next Thus.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: There is a result that says if $\sigma(a^\ast a)\subset(-\infty,0]$, then $a=0$.  I don't see exactly how it is used.

Comment: OK. With this result in hand the rest is fine. As we get $(bv)^*bv=0$ thus $-v^4=vb^*bv =0,$ i.e. $v=0.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: Ah. I see, thanks!

Comment: A non-unital algebra is only closed under the continuous functional calculus for functions $f$ such that $f(0)=0$.  These functions may be approximated by polynomials without constant terms,  so $f(a)$ lies in the $C^*$-algebra generated by $\{a\}$, as opposed to  $\{a,1\}$.